What part does AWS Global Accelerator play in established TCP connections
Reading the docs I can see that Global Accelerator (GA) routes to nearest region and has failover protection that will cause it to route to a different region if one fails.
I can't find any info that specifically answer the questions I have however.
In my setup, GA will direct to NLBs in two separate regions A and B. Let's call these NLBs, NLB-A and NLB-B. Behind these NLBs is my backend running on Fargate instances. The backends are websocket servers and therefore require persistent TCP connections.
The two regions are completely isolated with no data or state sharing, and need to remain this way for speed.
Assumption:
Once a websocket connection is opened, the client would have a TCP connection to one of the NLBs. Let's say NLB-A. So for an already established TCP connection, the IP of NLB-A is resolved.
Questions:

Is my assumption correct?
If so, what part does GA play (if any) in the route that websocket messages take to get to NLB-A? If not, what does the message route look like?
What does the client websocket see when region A fails?

